# Кэширование результата метода java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, кэширование, spring-boot

Всем доброго дня!

Пишу веб-приложение на spring.

В одном из бинов есть метод, возвращающий сгенерированную строку. Результирующая строка имеет 2 типовых значения и меняет своё значение всего **2 раза в год**. Так уж вышло, что эту самую строку мне необходимо выводить на **КАЖДОЙ** странице, а где-то даже не по 1 разу.

Есть ли какие-нибудь механизмы кэширования результатов метода?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Строго говоря, сам по себе вызов метода - если он не лезет в базу данных и не делает других относительно долгих вещей - не будет занимать очень уж много времени, поэтому даже подключение стандартного функционала скорее всего займет больше времени, чем будет выиграно процессорных секунд за счет кэширования.

Comment: Приложение тоже выдает запросы 2 раза в год?

Answer (score 0):

Да, в Spring есть [механизм кэширования](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache):

```
@Cacheable("semiannual-string")
public String someMethod() {
    ...
}
```